# jQuery $.fn - использование в native javascript/nodejs

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

Все мы знаем про `$.fn`, и как он нам помогает писать свои плагины для jQuery.
Например написали мы `$.fn.myFunc()`, делаем такое `$('#block').myFunc()`, теперь внутри `myFunc()` - `$('#block')` будет доступен как `this`.

Вот возникла у меня такая необходимость, в моем nodejs проекте, передать функции объект через точку, и чтоб та получила его внутри себя как `this`. Т.е. нужно сделать что-то вроде этого:

```js
var getSessionVars = function() {
   console.log(this.session);
}

//и где-то там далеко такой вызов

req.getSessionVars();
```

Такая конструкция работать не будет, мы получим:

> req.getSessionVars is not a function

Как заставить этот код работать, как можно реализовать подобное нативным js'oм?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В JavaScript у каждой функции есть свои методы `call`, `apply` и `bind`, которые позволяют передавать контекст вызову функции (грубо говоря передавать `this`).

1. `Function.prototype.call` ([документация](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)):

   Синтаксис: `fun.call(thisArg[, arg1[, arg2[, ...]]])`

   Первым аргументом передается объект контекста (`this`), а далее через запятую по необходимости перечисляются аргументы, которые необходимо передать функции в качестве параметров.

   Пример: `var result = getSessionVars.call(req, 'foo', 'bar');`
2. `Function.prototype.apply` ([документация](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)):

   Синтаксис: `fun.apply(thisArg, [argsArray])`

   Первым аргументом передается объект контекста (`this`), а вторым - массив аргументов, которые необходимо передать функции в качестве параметров.

   Пример: `var result = getSessionVars.apply(req, ['foo', 'bar']);`
3. `Function.prototype.bind` ([документация](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)):

   Синтаксис: `fun.bind(thisArg[, arg1[, arg2[, ...]]])`

   Первым аргументом передается объект контекста (`this`), а далее через запятую по необходимости перечисляются аргументы, которые необходимо передать функции в качестве параметров. На выходе получается новая функция с жестко определенным контекстом (`this`), которую в последствии можно использовать самостоятельно. Эту новую функцию тоже можно вызывать с аргументами, они будут добавлены к тем, которые были определены на момент создания "контекстной" функции.

   Пример:

   ```
   var getReqVars = getSessionVars.bind(req, 'foo');
   var result = getReqVars('bar');
   ```

Итого: каждый метод первым параметром принимает объект контекста (`this`); разница между `call` и `apply` в том, что в `apply` аргументы перечисляются через массив. `bind` позволяет создать новую функцию с прикрепленным контекстом для последующего использования.

Answer (score 1):

Можно добавлять функции в прототипы, наподобие:

```
String.prototype.test = function() {
    return "Hi, " + this + "!";
};

"Sanu".test(); // Hi, sanu!
```

Аналогично Вы можете расширить как любой конкретный объект, так все объекты: `Object.prototype`, так как все объекты являются потомками `Object`. Одно другого не исключает и Вы так же можете переопределить расширение в потомках.

Answer (score 0):

А что мешает реализовать механизм как у `jQuery`, т.е. заранее сохранить прототип объекта? Или использовать динамическое определение методов:

```
var getSessionVars = function() {
  console.log(this.session);
}

//и где-то там далеко такой вызов
req.getSessionVars = getSessionVars;
req.getSessionVars();
```